# jQuery show/hide issue on data grid

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I am facing a problem with the data gird. I have three to four datagrid one below the other and for each grid i have action buttons[select/del/copy/add] which i showing and hiding using jquery.

Each data grid has different id and show and hide controlled through jquery. But when i am clicking the first grid the next grid is also showing the control eventhough it has a different id.

I understand there is something advanced jquery scripting involved here, would be of great help if someone looks into this.

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/3fwyf/16/

thanks,
ravi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are toggling both groups of buttons..

If your html is structure as your example then you should remove those two toggles

```
$('#actn_btns').toggle();
$('#actn_btns1').toggle();
```

and add `$(this).closest('table').next().toggle();` in their place.

example at http://jsfiddle.net/3fwyf/19/

On another issue, you have duplicate id elements on the tables. Don't do that..

---

***Update***

the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) works like this

> *Get the first **ancestor** element that
>   matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and **progressing up
>   through the DOM** tree.*

The `.minus` and `.add` are not ancestors. So we need to first go up to a place where the `.child` and `.minus` elements are children to the current node and then go downwards and find them.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.minus, .add').toggle();
```

Comment: @Gaby, the script is working fine and i have done the same thing for the plus/minus images in the grid also. But there seems to be some problem with the script
$(this).closest('.minus, .add').next().toggle();

Comment: @Ravi, the closest finds only ancestors of the current element. the `.minus` and `.add` elements are in another cell at the same level. updating answer.

Comment: @Gaby, Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am working on the Add row on the grid i have this script which is working fine on a plain table but not working on the grid. Is it because of 2 grids having same ids?

 http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/3fwyf/26/

Comment: @ravi look at http://jsfiddle.net/3fwyf/27/ There are a lot of issues. Multiple identical IDs. This will cause multiple problems, first because it is invalid, and second because you cannot target an element directly. I have changed the buttons to have class instead of ID, the reset is commented-out as it only applies to forms and not input elements. In general you should rethink the naming conventions and the structure to avoid the `next()` and `prev()` as they tie you to a specific structure and are not really flexible.

Comment: @Gaby, for some reason jquery script is not working on local drive.
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/JbvJV/3/

Comment: wrap them in `$(function(){/*code should go here*/});`. In jsfiddle i removed it since it wraps it automatically by default. (*selection top left*). Also remove the label wrapped around the *add/remove/copy/select* buttons.

Comment: @Gaby, for add/copy/del i have written scripts which are having little problem. I have changed the Add function, inserting an empty row at the end of the table. For Copy is happeninng, but how can i target only selected rows to be copied..? I have used classes for the all data grids.

http://jsfiddle.net/3fwyf/36/

Comment: @Nahom, class selectors are case sensitive. so `$('.btncopy')` will not find an element with class `btnCopy`. You need to select rows that contain a checkbox which is checked. **http://jsfiddle.net/3fwyf/39/** Btw, you still have multiple identical IDs in your html, and your add method is using that..

Answer (score 1):

you should use the .next() jquery function to only select the next set of buttons to display

Comment: this goes like this

$('#actn_btns').next().toggle();..?

Comment: more like this: $(this).next('#actn_btns').toggle();